# Rep is lost even when no answer was received?

Tags: support, bounty

Is this how it normally works when a bounty is placed and no answer is received?

Comment: I've rebountied it for you.  Happy New Year.

Comment: Nice thank you!

Comment: I hope you get a decent answer out of it :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior.  Note the following from the [Help Center's Bounty Section](https://serverfault.com/help/bounty)

> **All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.**

A bounty *may* attract more attention, and possibly better answers, but it does not guarantee either.

Comment: As someone who's bountied more than once and not gotten answers, this is true. :P